# Do we need [measurement]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed [this question] using [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement). Should we burninate this tag?

Although measurement is a fundamental concept of all sciences (including political science), it doesn't seem to be political topic. In my mind, the primary usage of tags is to help users browse to questions they may be interested in. I have a hard time imagining this behavior for [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement).

There are currently 11 questions using this tag. They appear to all be related to different measures. One of them is related to measurement policy (related to the U.S.'s usage of non-metric measures).

Comment: As a general note about tags on smaller sites, I think [my answer here](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/51) applies on politics as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) should be **made a synonym** of the more commonly used [statistics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics). Except for the one question asking about the [metric system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/why-the-usa-forces-imperial-system-of-measurement-on-other-countries), every question using the tag seems to be using it to describe polling or statistical measurement of the economy or political beliefs. As they're currently used, there doesn't seem to be any gain to keeping them distinct.

Furthermore, I think [statistics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) is a more useful tag. The goal of tags is to guide people to questions that they have interest or expert knowledge in. While people can have experience with [statistics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) and an interest in ensuring that political decisions are informed by them, it's harder to imagine a significant group interested in [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) as distinct from [statistics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics).

Comment: `s/more useful/more common/`.  The gain of the current distinction is that it's factually correct.  Without measurement there can be no statistics, but not *vice versa*.

Answer (score -2):

In theory, there are experts on measurements, so the tag seems at least somewhat legit. I'd say leave it be unless there's good evidence it's actually causing harm. And yes, measurement can be a political topic, including policy as you noted; as well as a methodology in the political science topic (though the two should ideally have separate tags)

*As per @yannis's request posting as an answer.*

Answer (score -2):

**Yes**, *Politics.SE* needs [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement).

There's an [International Bureau of Weights and Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bureau_of_Weights_and_Measures), the USA has a [Weights and Measures Division](https://www.usa.gov/federal-agencies/weights-and-measures-division), and many nations have similar offices, and generally nations still have some differences in standards and interchangeability and perhaps always will.  Plus at any given time there's usually a few new units being considered to count things that are newly measurable -- sometimes the choice of unit has all sorts of political ramifications.

The idea that [measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) is somehow not considered political implies:

- we all take widely agreed upon measurements for granted,
- we wrongly must suppose that competent political offices with a long history of bipartisan concord are somehow not really *"political"*.
- a root error that the topic of politics properly concerns dispute more than agreement.

---

Also there are still measurements prone to significant partisan political controversy:

- Educational testing
- IQ points
- Prices, (as a metric of value, *e.g.* medical costs)
- Wages, (as a metric of job/worker value)
- Safety, (job safety, product safety, drug safety...)
- Carbon footprints, (pollution)

*Etc.*